# Login Button can not be found with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

https://www.sevenonemedia.de/tv/programm/programmwochen

Here I want to login:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

options = Options()
chrome_path = "T:/Markus/WebScrapingExample/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,chrome_options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1280, 720) 

time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://www.sevenonemedia.de/tv/programm/programmwochen")
driver.find_element_by_id("_58_login").send_keys("name")
driver.find_element_by_id("_58_password").send_keys("pw")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sign-in-button"]').click()

ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
```

This is my error[image]

Id is there.  Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

hi first things you should not give your password to all of the stackoverflow community :)

you can't click on the button because there is a popup at the bottom of the page and you have to click on it first for selenium it's hidding your button

last is that the totality of your code ?
if yes you forgot

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() #or any other webdriver
```

you have not create driver without this line

EDIT !!

it wasn't working with only the modification above but with this one its good

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


time.sleep(5)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.sevenonemedia.de/tv/programm/programmwochen")
driver.find_element_by_id("_58_login").send_keys("login")
driver.find_element_by_id("_58_password").send_keys("pssd")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/a").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#_58_fm > fieldset:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6) > button:nth-child(1)").click()
```

this work :)

sometime css selector a safer and work better

Comment: thank you! Would you please edit the user and password :). Thank you :)

Comment: ho yes i'm stupid sorry i say it and i make the same mistake x)

Answer (score 0):

This page contains duplicate of element with ID `sign-in-button`. If your selector points to more than one element, driver always takes the first from the top of the DOM one which is not interactable in this case. You must refer to the second element with this id. Try this selector for "Sign in" button:

```
//*[@id="aheadcustom_p_p_id_58"]//button
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the *Login*  button you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.sevenonemedia.de/tv/programm/programmwochen")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@title='Anmelden' and not(contains(@name,'INSTANCE'))]"))).send_keys("a.mai@mediaplus.com")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Passwort' and not(contains(@name,'INSTANCE'))]").send_keys("Edidaten17")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@title='Passwort' and not(contains(@name,'INSTANCE'))]//following::button[1]").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: successful.png]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your button locator isn't unique on the page. It finds two buttons, the first of which is not visible which causes the `ElementNotInteractableException`.

The simple fix is to use the CSS selector below

```
#main-content #sign-in-button
```

That will find only the button you want. So your last few lines of code would be

```
driver.find_element_by_id("_58_login").send_keys("name")
driver.find_element_by_id("_58_password").send_keys("pw")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#main-content #sign-in-button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
sleep(1)
login_box = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
login_box.click()
```

this is for facebook login button, just inspect the website and see the id/name/type to make your code automate to work properly